# Preserve the input voltage range while reducing part count for a power supply

Tags: power-supply, bom

I have a design which uses a TPS40200 switching regulator that gives out 5V at 2A (max) by accepting input voltages anywhere between 8V to 40V. However, I now need the same 5V at not more than 800mA but the pin count has to reduce significantly. I was thinking of using a 7805 that just needs a input and output capacitor but it can accept input voltages only upto 30V. Is there a way to preserve the input voltage range while reducing the part count? The switching regualtor circuit has a BOM count of 24 and this needs to come down to not more than 5.

Comment: Might check "Simple Switcher" - fairly low part count, designed to be almost a drop in for 7805.

Comment: Thanks. This was useful. The [LMR16006](http://www.ti.com/product/LMR16006) from TI looks promising.

Answer (score 2):

> I was thinking of using a 7805 that just needs a input and output
>   capacitor

If it *could* run from 40 volts then the device would drop 35 volts at a current of 0.8 amps and dissipate 35 x 0.8 watts. That's 28 watts and to be largely avoided as a design idea. You need to concentrate on switching regulators because of their far superior power efficiency.

Here's a design that uses 8 parts: -

[image]

> BOM count of 24 and this needs to come down to not more than 5

I suspect that small board area and low power dissipation might trump BoM count.

Comment: Thanks. Though the LT device you've mentioned is too expensive in my part of the world, I did find the [LMR16006](http://www.ti.com/product/LMR16006) from TI. It has a current rating of only 600mA but it should do.